# Make pin/unpin edits more obvious

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Currently, when someone either pins or unpins an example it's very easy to miss. The edit summary, explaining what they did will mention it, albeit in small text:

[image]

And if you want to actually see the pin that's been removed, first you need to find it in the example because it hasn't necessarily been expanded (if they didn't do other edits)

[image]

And even after expanding, there's no clear highlighting of the fact that the pin was removed, it's just absent:

[image]

This makes it far too easy to overlook, and hard to find if you just spot the "example unpinned" note. Pinning is very important because it's currently the only direct way to change the order of examples. It's not a side note to gloss over when approving/rejecting.

Comment: Actually, the diff is misleading. The case you've shown makes no change in pinning (the edit summary is lying). I've made a test change with explicitly [unpinned example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8WfFI.png), and that's what it looks like: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Jcp4o.png

Comment: @Roman Ah, interesting. Now I'm wondering if this is a bug or just an odd design choice.

Comment: Reading this question makes me feel like I've approved some changes that have pinned/unpinned stuff and I didn't even realize it at the time...